# generating confusion matrix in keras for multiclass classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, confusion-matrix

Getting accuracy up to 98% by training model but confusion matrix shows very high miss-classification.

I am working on multiclass classification using keras with transfer learning approach on pre-trained VGG16 model.

The problem is to classify the images into 5 types of tomato diseases using CNN.

There are 5 disease classes with 6970 training images and 70 testing images.

Training model shows 98.65% accuracy while testing shows 94% accuracy.

But the problem is when I am generating confusion matrix it shows very high miss-classification.

someone please help me, whether my code is wrong or the model is wrong? I am  confused whether my model is giving me correct results or not.

And if someone can explain me how keras actually calculate the accuracy using model.fit_generator Function because applying the general formula of accuracy on confusion matrix is not giving me same results as keras have calculated.

For testing the dataset code is:

```
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
test_dir,
target_size=(150, 150),
batch_size=20,
class_mode='categorical')
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, steps=50)
print('test acc:', test_acc)
```

I found the code to generate confusion matrix from one of the forum;

code is:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,classification_report
batch_size = 20
num_of_test_samples = 70
predictions = model.predict_generator(test_generator,  num_of_test_samples // batch_size+1)

y_pred = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

true_classes = test_generator.classes

class_labels = list(test_generator.class_indices.keys())   

print(class_labels)

print(confusion_matrix(test_generator.classes, y_pred))

report = classification_report(true_classes, y_pred, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)
```

Following are the results I get:

Testing accuracy:

```
Found 70 images belonging to 5 classes.
test acc: 0.9420454461466182
```

Results of Confusion matrix:

```
['TEB', 'TH', 'TLB', 'TLM', 'TSL']
[[2 3 2 4 3]
 [4 2 3 0 5]
 [3 3 3 2 3]
 [3 3 2 4 2]
 [2 2 4 4 2]]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         TEB       0.14      0.14      0.14        14
          TH       0.15      0.14      0.15        14
         TLB       0.21      0.21      0.21        14
         TLM       0.29      0.29      0.29        14
         TSL       0.13      0.14      0.14        14

   micro avg       0.19      0.19      0.19        70
   macro avg       0.19      0.19      0.19        70
weighted avg       0.19      0.19      0.19        70
```

Answer (score 3):

While creating the test data generator, the `flow_from_directory` method takes `shuffle=True` parameter by default. Therefore, when you predict by plugging in the generator instance, the predictions are not shown in the same order as the true classes are. This is the reason you are getting the right predictions, but in a different order. So, the confusion matrix is showing bad performance.

Just set shuffle to False in the test data generator and the predictions will come in the right order. As the purpose of validation/test data is to evaluate the model, you can almost always set shuffle to False.

Answer (score 1):

The test labels should be class_indices rather than classes

```
true_classes = test_generator.class_indices
```

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your answer. I updated the code but it gives me the following   error: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 147]

Comment: Can you post the shape of true_classes and y_pred?

Comment: For true classes: i am getting class indices per image as : classes [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4] and y_pred gives me prediction of particular images with its respective classes as: y_pred [1 0 4 0 4 3 4 0 0 3 0 2 4 1 3 4 3 2 1 3 4 0 2 1 1 1 4 2 4 1 1 0 0 2 4 4 4 4 3 3 4 0 2 3 3 2 0 2 4 1 0 3 0 4 0 3 1 4 1 0 4 3 0 4 2 0 2 0 3 0 0 3 2]

Comment: Try evaluate_generator instead of predict_generator while creating predictions

Comment: It gives me following error: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Comment: Check the shape of y_pred then

Comment: As i have posted above the output shows that it has 14 samples for 5 classes. Can you please tell me if my code is correct or not.

Comment: This is not correct, it should be true_classes = test_generator.class

Answer (score 1):

Dear always do the following for any classification performance parameters:

1. first reset the generator which you are using in prediction
2. put shuffle equal to false in flow_from_directory()

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the party but maybe you aren't preprocessing test data the same way as train ones. Try to import preprocessing function from VGG16 and add it to generator as parameter (preprocessing_function).

Comment: But I don't understand the need for pre-processing the test data. If the model is trained then it should directly give the answers of test data. Maybe I am not understanding what you are suggesting. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Depending on model you are using there are ways you have to preprocess the input. It doesn't matter really if it is training or testing input. 
Let's say you are using Vgg16 from Keras. I think the weights were are adopted from caffe. Caffe does use substracting the mean of dataset over channels of image as preprocessing. Those are then feed in the network. As network was trained using such images, you have to preprocess the test data in same manner.

Comment: Quick example: Let's say there a mean of R color channel equal to 113. The network was taught with such preprocessing. So here come's the pixel with R channel value of 200. If you substract it by 113, you get 87, but if you won't, it stays 200. As there is a lot of summing and multiplying ongoing in the network, the network is going to respond to such non-processed image in a vastly different manner.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I get it. But then why am I not getting the confusion matrix right. I don't understand what is the problem in my code.

Comment: Try googling versions of keras, tf, cudnn and CUDA that works together and reinstalling them to those versions. Sometimes, there will be mismatch, that isn't really obvious and will result into strange behaviour when evaluating the model. I have run into that problem several times. Basically, training and val accuracy will be great during training, but model will be useless in the testing mode.